# List in scala -getting element from the right side

Tags: list, scala

I have started learning scala and I wonder is there a way I could get elements in the List from the right side

For example

```
val myList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

if I write`myList(-1)` I would get `5`.

Is there any simple way to get it done or I'll have to write my own function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myList.last
```

? Remember that this operation has O(n) complexity for `List`. Also you can simply reverse the list and use normal indices:

```
myList.reverse(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala's `List` is a singly linked list, and therefore indexed lookup on it would be a linear time operation. Since you are interested in backward indices, you'll also have to call `.length` method, which is a linear time operation as well.

If you need to perform indexed access, `List` is probably not the right data structure to use. You should instead use `Vector` which is a sequence type with efficient indexed access (takes constant time effectively).

Refer [this link](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) for an overview of performance characteristics of various Scala collections.

```
scala> val v = Vector(3, 4, 5, 2)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(3, 4, 5, 2)

scala> v(v.length - 1)
res21: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList(myList.length-1-index)
```

Note then myList.length has O(n) complexity, and querying for specific index has O(index).

Answer (score 0):

To do something like:

`myList(-n)`

You can define an implicit conversion that lets you do:

`myList.getFromRight(n)`

Here is the code for the implicit conversion. It will create a new getFromRight method on all Seqs, so it will work on Lists, Vectors, etc.

```
implicit def getFromRightImpl[A](s: Seq[A]) = new {
  def getFromRight(n: Int) = s(s.length - n)
}
```

And here are some examples:

```
scala> val v = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> v.getFromRight(1)
res4: Int = 4

scala> l.getFromRight(3)
res5: Int = 2
```

Implicit conversions are a rather advanced Scala feature, but this is one of the perfect use cases for them: when an object is lacking methods you think it should have, but modifying it with inheritance is not an option, you can define an implicit conversion to another object with the methods you want.

Comment: No. If functionality is missing, write a trait.

Comment: @Ant: To be used at object creation time, like `new List with AddedFunctionalityTrait`? I don't think that would play nice with creating objects from companion objects (`List(1,2)`, etc.) or with getting objects from code not under your control.